# zip command behaving differently in different bash scripts

Tags: linux, bash, zip, centos7

I have 2 bash scripts that use a zip command but one script zip command gives the following error.

> zip warning: name not matched: file1.txt file2.txt

This is the command that I am using in both scripts.

```
zip "${updates_zip}.patch.zip" $(ls)
```

I tried to print the directory's contents and file1.txt and file2.txt exist but the zip command still gives the above error.
It seems in 1 script it considers `file1.txt file2.txt` 2 different files but in another script, it is considering `file1.txt file2.txt` a single file having a space char in the name. However, I am not enclosing file names in quotes. Both scripts have the zip command written in exactly the same way as mentioned above.

Comment: Why not break that oneliner down into its individual steps and assign each result to individual variables? Debugging becomes easier. Edit: After the edit: Please provide a [mre] and also examples from what that `$(ls)` prints. It looks like a weak link.

Comment: yeah I tried the zip command without password, But its still same

Comment: I've provided the zip command that gives the error. can't share the full script.

Comment: I'm not asking for the full script. That's not what a [mre] is.

Comment: $(ls) prints the names of the files in current directory

Comment: @AmarjitSingh When you use `$(ls)`, the shell might or might not correctly split the output into separate filenames (see: ["Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)). There are a number of ways it can fail, and this is *probably* what's causing trouble in your case. But without a reproducible example, it's impossible to say for sure.

Comment: Do not use `$(ls)`. Use `*` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your other script probably has IFS variable modified. Instead of using ls, just use filename expansion like the following.

```
zip "${updates_zip}.patch.zip" *.txt
```